# List index out of range even when loops don't iterate on the lists

Tags: python, indexing

I'm a beginner at python coding and I've been trying to do this exercise to remove all adjacent characters from a list of integers to a single element using the following block of code:

```
#nums is a list of integers with repeating adjacent characters. For eg. [1,2,2,2,3,3]

length = len(nums)
for i in range(length):
    while nums[i] == nums[i+1]:
            del(nums[i+1])
            length-=1
```

I keep getting the list index out of range error on the while loop, but since neither of the loops depends on the indices of nums directly, then how am I violating the bounds of the list?

I have previously checked with other answers to the same problem which all have solutions that relate to list comprehension which I don't want to apply to my code. Also, I'm aware of other approaches to removing adjacent elements but I would like to know what was wrong with my bit of code here for learning purposes. Thanks in advance.

Comment: try printing `i` and `nums` within your `while` loop

Comment: `while nums[i] == nums[i+1]` might have an issue on last iteration..!

Comment: Just use `for i in range(length-1):`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've added a check for confirming length. Is this what you want? It simply executes the loop if items are available.

```
nums = [1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3]

length = len(nums)
for i in range(length):
    while i < length-1 and nums[i] == nums[i + 1] :
        del (nums[i + 1])
        length -= 1

print(nums)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This solved my problem. I would appreciate it if you could elaborate on why this worked and where my logic was flawed.

Comment: I've added i < length-1 before evaluating nums[i+1]. The problem was that whenever the last element reached, it was checking for the element at next position which won't be available at the instant. The check I've added prevents that

Comment: Would this have worked if  'length = len(nums) - 1' to prevent i from iterating till the last element instead of placing the check in the while loop?

Comment: No that won't work. Length is being decremented inside loop. If you minus 1 the length at beginning, it will still be the same case except for one element. Deletion of list item and subtracting the length value are the things to look for here

Answer (score 0):

You can track array from end to start by `length-1` like this:

```
nums = [1,2,2,2,3,3]
length = len(nums)
for i in reversed(range(length-1)):
    while (nums[i] == nums[i-1]):
        del(nums[i])

print(nums)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 errors here.

1. You are iterating over a range which cannot be indexed; in this case, the `nums[len(nums)]` does not exist. Remember Python indexing begins at 0.
2. You are modifying your list as you iterate. Don't do this, as the length of your list will change and your iteration will not work as intended.

Here is some code that works:

```
nums = [1,2,2,2,3,3]
length = len(nums)

items = []
for i in range(length-1):
    if nums[i] == nums[i+1]:
        items.append(i+1)

res = [i for i, j in enumerate(nums) if i not in items]

# [1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the valuable advice. I'll keep this in mind. I was aware of the creating another list and filtering the values approach but I wanted to know the specific mistake in my snippet of code. Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 0):

(Python 3.6)
If you want remove all duplicate and keep the ordering:

```
 >>> a = [1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 6, 3 ]
 >>> list(dict.fromkeys(a))
 [1, 2, 3, 4, 6]
```

But it will remove the last 3 too.